# Find the Process run by nohup command

Tags: linux, process, background, ps, nohup

I run a server executable in Centos using the following command `"nohup server &"`. Now I need to kill the process `"server"`. But I tried `"ps -a"` command to get the `PID` but I couldnt get the process. Now how to kill the `"server"` now?

Comment: ps auxwww|grep -i 'server' should return all process which has 'server' in them. Otherwise, server may have already stopped.

Comment: @Usman saleem thanks this solves my answer. I have One more doubt "nohup server &" is the right command, to run a process backgroung even if i close the terminal?

Comment: @Mikhail thanks this solves my answer. I have One more doubt "nohup server &" is the right command, to run a process background even if i close the terminal?

Comment: Yes it is, you can determine the PID right when you invoke the command: 'nohup server &' followed by 'print $! >> server_pid_file'

Comment: yes, using nohup command means that your 'server' process will discard 'HUP' interrupt which OS sends when you close the terminal. It will also discard 'kill -HUP pid' or 'kill -1 pid'.

Comment: You might also want to use `batch` or `at` to run your `server`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ps auxwww|grep -i 'server'` should return all process which has `server` in them. Otherwise, server may have already stopped.

You should be able to determine the PID (and store it in a file) as follows:

```
nohup server &
print $! >> my_server.pid
```

Answer (score 15):

If a nohup.out file was created, you may run in bash:

```
# lsof nohup.out
```

it will return the pid which created/is running the file

best regards!

Answer (score 5):

There is no definitive way to catch the exact process with the help of `ps` command, but you can use the following:

```
ps -a | grep "server"
```

You will get a list of all the processes running with the name "server"

Or, you can use any other keywords as well to grep the ps output.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to launch a server in centos is with the service command.

So
`service httpd start`

There is a chance that you want to write your program as a daemon

> A daemon (or service) is a background process that is designed to run
>   autonomously,with little or not user intervention. The Apache web
>   server http daemon (httpd) is one such example of a daemon. It waits
>   in the background listening on specific ports, and serves up pages or
>   processes scripts, based on the type of request.

See http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

Comment: I just need to run my executable background? can you give some example?

Comment: @2vision2 you want to write your program like a linux daemon see http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html