# How to know if the process is set NOHUP?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process

Using jobs I know the process is running.

```
bash-4.2$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 test.sh &
```

I wanted it to be set NOHUP so that it won't be killed when I exit. I used

```
disown
```

and

```
bash-4.2$ jobs
```

shows nothing. I'm not sure if the process is set NOHUP or not. I'm curious about this because after I read the manual it says

```
disown -h
```

should be used to set NOHUP.

**Edit**

I don't think the link [Find the Process run by nohup command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151928/find-the-process-run-by-nohup-command) helps. The question is different than that one.

I'm gonna restate my problem. I run a program without nohup, and later I wanted it to be set NOHUP so that it won't be killed when I exit the system. So I used `disown`, but later I found the manual says I should have used `disown -h` to set NOHUP. I want to check if my process is set NOHUP or not successfully. If not, what can I do to set it to be NOHUP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the Process run by nohup command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151928/find-the-process-run-by-nohup-command)

Comment: @jaypal I've read the thread but I still don't figure out which column of `ps` shows if NOHUP is set? It didn't state the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: I put the answer..hope be helpful

Comment: @Marcus Thornton I updated mu answer..See the answer plz

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I know two ways my be helpful:

**1)** Whenever a process is running over `nohup` It writes output on ~/nohup.out . So you can check this file by running command `find -cmin 2`. It shows you if nohup.out is changing each 2 seconds or not.
If it is changing you would understand that sth is running by `nohup` command, after that you can check it with `lsof` and continue your checking...

**2)** If you logout from specific user andgo to `tty` then do `ps aux | grep <user>` or `ps aux | grep ?` then you can understand that is running with nohup command... because there is no pts then it shows you **?** instead...

useful command:

```
ps aux | grep <program> | awk -F" " '{print $7}'
```

Hope to be helpful

Comment: I cannot see any output of `jobs` but `ps -ef` still shows the pid. What does it mean? I want to know if the process is set NOHUP.

Comment: ask your question on `super user` and `unix&linux` ... you can find it on those Q&A

Comment: I know I could use `nohup` to set NOHUP. I question here is how to ckeck the dispatched process is set NOHUP or not.